# Шахматный конь, рекурсия, максимумы

Tags: c, алгоритм

*Имеется шахматная доска 8х8. Предположим в каждой клетке доски содержится некоторое количество яблок. Шахматная фигура “конь” может ходить по классическим правилами хода коня. Оказываясь в очередной клетке, конь собирает все яблоки, которые в ней находятся. Имеется ограничения на количество ходов. Ваша программа должна принимать на вход следующие аргументы: максимальное число ходов, имя файла, содержащего схему заполнения шахматной доски яблоками. Строки в файле соответствуют строкам шахматной доски, строки разделяются переносами. Числа в строках разделяются пробелами. Ваша программа должна вывести максимально возможное количество собираемых яблок конем, при заданном ограничении ходов и произвольном выборе начальной позиции.*

Собственно, хотелось бы понять, каким образом/методом следует решать эту задачу. Сам код мне, конечно, нужен, но думаю и сам смогу написать программу, если пойму её основную идею.
Была идея решать через жадный алгоритм, передвигаясь в клетку, содержащую в себе максимально возможное число яблок (сравнивал количество яблок в каждой из клеток, доступных в данный момент и шел в клетку с максимальным числом), но, как мне кажется, это решение, мягко говоря, не совсем верное. Задача должна содержать в себе рекурсию. Подайте идею решения данной
проги или посоветуйте литературы по этой теме, пожалуйста. 
Заранее благодарю! :D

Comment: Хм. А причём тут шахматный конь?

Comment: При том, что я умудрился вставить не то условие. Увы, недосып - виноват =)

Comment: Помнится что-то подобное решали (не помню какая конкретно задача была, но точно про коня). Нужно рассматривать шахматную доску как граф (как уже писал @KoVadim), удобнее всего с графом работать с помощью списка смежности. А дальше я ничего умнее перебора предложить не могу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, что подобные задачи решаются полным перебором. То есть, для каждой клетки делаем полный перебор ходов. Да, это будет долго, но...

Специалисты могут решат задачу другим способом. Шахматная доска для коня - это граф. Кол-во яблок в клетке - это значение в вершине. Задача сводиться к поиску цепочки с максимальной суммой. В теории графов есть много алгоритмов для поиска [кратчайшего пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8), но думаю, они легко "перевернутся".

Comment: Полный перебор не будет работать, так как каждый шаг имеет [ветвление 2..8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F#mediaviewer/File:Knight%27s_graph_showing_number_of_possible_moves.svg) и количество шагов может достигать 63 т.е., порядка 2**63..8**63 операций (ближе ко второй цифре) -- это 20..50 нулей в после единички в числе.

Answer (score 4):

Ну и, помимо упомянутого графа, так же стоит добавить, что Ваш вариант с жадный алгоритмом неверен. Просто потому, что путь 2-1 даст меньше, чем путь 1-9, который будет проигнорирован подобным жадным алгоритмом.

Стоит заметить, что конь ходит в любую точку доски за 4-5 ходов, поэтому хороший граф будет очень запутанным в данной задаче и достаточно сложен в построении и анализе. Поэтому, для упрощения можно воспользоваться его частным видом - неориентированным восьминарным (по числу ходов коня) [деревом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дерево_(теория_графов)#.D0.94.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE) высотой в ограничение ходов коня.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, будет ли он работать в этом случае, но так как в задаче нужно найти только *"максимально возможное количество собираемых яблок коне"* без запоминания пройденного пути, то возможна эффективная реализация с помощью [динамического программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%E8%ED%E0%EC%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%EE%E5_%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5), если в задаче существует оптимальная подструктура (если оптимальное решение подзадачи, является частью оптимального решения большей задачи).